# eclipse - new breakpoints won't break after run has started

Tags: c, eclipse

I have this strange error. It started some time ago and I don't know what caused it (it wasn't always like that):

I run eclipse CDT over Ubuntu 16. I can set breakpoints, before run has started, and they break correctly.

But once I started the run, I can set new breakpoints, but they won't break. The program just skips them.

Any idea why this is caused?